# No dangling reference for std::min in libc++

Tags: c++, reference, clang++, libc++, object-lifetime

It is well known (or it should be) that binding the result of [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) to a `const` reference is a very bad idea, whenever one of the arguments of `std::min` is a rvalue, since `const` reference binding is not propagated through function return. So the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int n = 42;
    const int& r = std::min(n - 1, n + 1); // r is dangling after this line
    std::cout << r;
}
```

should produce undefined behaviour since `r` is dangling. And indeed, when compiling with gcc5.2 with `-Wall -O3` the compiler spits

> warning: `<anonymous>` is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

However, compiling with clang (llvm 7.0.0) using the same flags (even including `-Wextra`) does not emit any warning, and the program seems to "work", i.e. displays `41`.

**Question:** Is the clang using a "safe" version of `std::min`? Like a version that uses some SFINAE to return by value whenever one of the arguments is a rvalue? Or is it simply not required to emit any diagnostic and the program "happens" to produce the "right" result in this UB scenario?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined...

Comment: @T.C. Yes I know, was just curios whether clang fixed this, as it is a well known issue, and does not emit any warning whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is UB.  libc++ does not protect you from this in any way.

Comment: It's the nastiest kind of UB - it appears to work fine.